# Python ImportError: No module named path.X, but works with nosetests

Tags: python, python-2.7, nose

In `level1/level2/bar.py`, when trying to import a variable `foo` from `level1/foo.py`, I'm getting an error:

```
ImportError: No module named level1.foo
```

**level1/foo.py**

```
bar = 123
```

**level1/level2/bar.py**

```
import level1.foo
print level1.foo.bar
```

However when running `nosetests` defined in `level1/level2/test_bar.py`, it is able to locate `level1.foo.py`!

**level1/level2/test_bar.py**

```
import level1.foo

def test_foobar():
    print level1.foo.bar
```

Why is it possible to import via `level1.foo` during a nosetest, but not able to do so with a regular python script?

Here's the file structures, there are `__init__.py` files in each directory as well.

[image]

**Additionallly,** my friend using PyCharm does not seem to face such a problem. Does PyCharm automatically handle these imports, but breaks outside of PyCharm unless the root of the project is added to `PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a PYTHONPATH issue. If you are running nosetests from the `app` directory, the level1.foo import will be available. If you are running `level1/level2/bar.py` from the `apps/level1/level2` directory, level1.foo would not (necessarily) be in your path.